# Displaying Foreign Key Options in django restframework view

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble displaying all the `jobs` as options in the `apply` url view see image below.

[image]

I am getting the error which says

`Lists are not currently supported in HTML input`

The main function I am looking for is for a list of jobs that were posted to be available for selection when applying for the job.

**models.py**

```
class Job(models.Model):
  """A Job used to create a job posting"""
  user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
  )
  description = models.TextField()
  job_type = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=JOB_TYPE_CHOICES, default='Full-Time')
  city = models.CharField(max_length=255)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.description[:50]


class Applicant(models.Model):
  """A applicant that can apply to a job"""
  job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='applicants', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
  phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
  resume = models.FileField(upload_to=resume_file_path, validators=[validate_file_extension])

  def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name
```

I've removed some of the attributes in `Job` so that the code is not so long.

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from core.models import Job, Applicant


class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  """Serializer for tag objects"""
  applicants = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Job
    fields = ('id', 'description', 'job_type', 'city', 'state', 'salary', 'position', 'employer', 'created_date', 'is_active', 'applicants')
    read_only_fields = ('id',)
 

  def create(self, validated_data):
    """Create a job posting with user and return it"""
    return Job.objects.create(**validated_data)


class ApplyJobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  """Serializer for applying to jobs"""
  jobs = JobSerializer(many=True, queryset=Job.objects.all())

  class Meta:
    model = Applicant
    fields = ('id','jobs', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'resume')
    read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

**views.py**

```
class ApplyJobView(generics.CreateAPIView):
  """Allows applicants to apply for jobs"""
  serializer_class = serializers.ApplyJobSerializer
```

I've tried adding a `queryset=Job.objects.all()` as an argument to the `JobSerializer()` in the `ApplyJobSerializer` class in my serializers.py field. However I get an error that says

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select an existing job in the form.

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for tag objects"""
    applicants = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('__all__')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a job posting with user and return it"""
        return Job.objects.create(**validated_data)


class ApplyJobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for applying to jobs"""
    jobs = JobSerializer(many=True, queryset=Job.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Applicant
        fields = ('__all__')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

This result as I have created a new job with `description` is `desc`
[image]

Comment: I have tried this in the past and again just now and its not displaying anything on the web browser.

Comment: Do you mean that the field `jobs` don't display in the form create? if YES, because of this setting: `read_only=True`.

Comment: Yes the `jobs` don't display. I got rid of the `read_only=True` and now its sayings `lists are not currently supported in HTML input.`

Comment: Got it, so do you want to create a new job or select an existing job inside that form?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please help to check!